# Serving war file on tomcat docker container

Tags: docker, tomcat

I'm trying to run my java app on a docker container. I'm using a tomcat server locally and it's working fine. I'm new to java/tomcat/docker so there's something I might be very well missing something very simple but I assumed just pointing my local war file to `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps` would be enough.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```yaml
tomcat-dev:
  image: tomcat:8.5.38
  environment:
    - TOMCAT_USERNAME=root
    - TOMCAT_PASSWORD=root
  ports:
    - "8888:8080"
  volumes:
    - /target/npmanager.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/npmanager.war

mysql-dev:
  image: mysql:8.0.2
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_DATABASE: npmanagercd
  volumes:
    - /mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
  ports:
    - "3308:3306"
```

I can see the `npmanager.war` file in the webapps directory but I can't access my app. My localhost still shows me the tomcat page instead of the "Hello, World" I see when I run it from my local install of tomcat.

Is there something I'm missing about deploying war files on tomcat?

Comment: What URL are you using? `http://xxx:8080/npmanager` ?

Comment: @PeterRader `http://xxx:8888/npmanager`. On `http://xxx:8888/` I see the tomcat setup page

Comment: Can you check if war file got extracted properly ?

Comment: @Ros5292 what is that supposed to look like? This is what I'm seeing `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps# ROOT  docs  examples  host-manager  manager  npmanager.war`

Comment: yeah that means your war file not deployed, if it would have deployed there should be `npmanager` folder which gets extracted from `npmanager.war` file

Comment: @Ros5292 is there something that needs to be done to deploy the war file?

Comment: How you starting your docker container ? docker-compose up ?

Comment: @Ros5292 Yup. I did notice that I had my tomcat volume mapped to `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/npmanager.war` when it should have been `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/`. But now the /webapps directory is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I finally got it working. I wanted to post this answer here if it would help anyone else, but in all honestly I'm not sure I completely understand it.

I had to create a separate Dockerfile for the tomcat image:

```
FROM tomcat:8.5.38
ADD ./target/npmanager.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
CMD chmod +x /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

And then build that image in the docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'

services:

tomcat-dev:
  build: .
  environment:
    TOMCAT_USERNAME: root
    TOMCAT_PASSWORD: root
  ports:
    - "8888:8080"

mysql-dev:
  image: mysql:8.0.2
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_DATABASE: npmanager
  volumes:
    - /mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
  ports:
    - "3308:3306"
```

Comment: Not sure exactly how it solved your problem. But I can tell you there should only be one CMD line. its likely that you meant to write "RUN chmod +x ..." instead of "CMD chmod"

Comment: but with this you have to build the docker image all the time. I think the original problem is to be able to deploy the war file to the tomcat container so it will pick up the new changes without rebuilding the docker image.